# How to explain this program calculating 3/4*x using bit operation?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For a given value of `int` type, calculating 3/4*x using the most basic bit operations(i.e. no `while`/`for` or other C control logic. Also suppose `sizeof(int) = 4 (Byte)`. And the hard point is to truncate towards 0 and avoiding overflow.

What I have tried:

Suppose expressing `x` as its binary form:
`x = [b_31 b_30 ... b_2 b_1 b_0]`
Then `3/4*x = x/2 + x/4 = ([b_31 ... b_1 0] + b_0) >> 1 + ([b_31 ... b_2 0 0] + b_1 b_0) >> 2`
Then using `x>>1 + x>>2` we can get `[b_31 ... b_1 0]>>1 + [b_31 ... b_2 0 0]>>2` without precision lost or overflow problem, leaving only `[b_0 0] + [b_1 b_0]>> 2` to deal with. But I got stuck here for I had no idea how to implement truncating towards zero.

Comparing to the following sample program, I found two variables `x_mask` and `bias` used. I guess they are used to solve the truncate problem since for a negative number `bias` will always be `11` and for a positive number `00`. Can anyone help explain the logic here?

```
int threefourths(int x) {
     int xl2 = x & 0x3;
     int xl1 = (x&1) << 1;
     int x_mask = x >> ((sizeof(int)<<3)-1);
     int bias = x_mask & 3;
     int incr = (xl2+xl1+bias) >> 2;
     int s2 = x >> 2;
     int s1 = x >> 1;
     return s1 + s2 + incr;
     }
```

Comment: 3/4 = 1/2 + 1/4. So all code except for the last two lines is for rounding. It *looks* a bit overly complicated, but without knowing what rounding is desired it is impossible to know how to potentially simplify it. So the first task here would be to reverse engineer what kind of rounding the current code implements. Have you done that?

Comment: I verified that the code in `threefourth()` computes `(int)((double)x * 0.75)`, i.e. the mathematical result rounded to zero, for all possible inputs `x`. Note that the code contains a number of right shifts of potentially negative data, invoking *implementation defined* behavior according to the C standard. But the code relies on the right shifts in the computation of `s1` and `s2`to be *arithmetic* right shifts. I can't explain the rounding logic of this code. I can provide *equivalent* code whose rounding logic I *can *explain, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to compute `0.75 * x`, with the result rounded towards 0. Because `0.75 == 0.5 + 0.25`, computing it as `(x >> 1) + (x >> 2)` is a good approximation, *provided* the right shifts are mapped to *arithmetic* right shift instructions, something ISO C does *not* guarantee. The standard specifies:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. [...] If
>   E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is
>   implementation-defined.

The approximation will frequently underestimate the desired result, because (1) the division of negative integers by arithmetic right shift rounds to negative infinity, and (2) truncation both of the two individual terms results in an underestimation compared to truncating once, as in the reference computation.

So we know that a correction may need to be applied, and such a correction must be zero or positive. Because the division is by `4`, there are four remainder cases to consider per sign-bit setting, giving a total of eight cases. In the posted code, the four remainder cases are extracted as `x & 3` which is the same as `x % 4`. I am not able to follow the details of code further, but would like to show a alternative that is easier to understand.

A simple enumeration of the eight possible cases shows that corrections are needed as shown in the table below. The value of the corrections is determined by subtracting the approximation `(x >> 1) + (x >> 2)` from the reference result, for representative values belonging to each of the eight classes, e.g. `x` in [`0x7ffffffc`, `0x80000003`]. The corrections for negative arguments are larger than those for positive arguments because both of the underestimation effects enumerated above combine.

```
   s = sign bit, e.g. x<31>, x1 = bit x<1>, x0 = bit x<0>

   x%4 s x1 x0 | corr
   ------------+-----
    0  0  0  0 |  0
    1  0  0  1 |  0
    2  0  1  0 |  0
    3  0  1  1 |  1
    0  1  0  0 |  0
    1  1  0  1 |  1
    2  1  1  0 |  1
    3  1  1  1 |  2
```

It is straightforward to see that the required correction equates to `(x0 & x1) + (s & (x0 | x1))`. We can slightly optimize this at the cost of clarity, as shown in the following implementation:

```c
int threefourths (int x) 
{
    int s2 = x >> 2; // ensure this maps to arithmetic right shift instruction
    int s1 = x >> 1; // ensure this maps to arithmetic right shift instruction
    unsigned int ux = (unsigned int)x;
    unsigned int s = ux >> (sizeof(ux) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
#if READABILITY
    unsigned int x0 = ux & 1;
    unsigned int x1 = s1 & 1;
    unsigned int corr = (x0 & x1) + (s & (x0 | x1));
#else // SPEED
    unsigned int corr = ((ux & s1) & 1) + (s & (ux | s1));
#endif // REDABILITY vs SPEED
    return (int)(s1 + s2 + corr);
}

int ref_threefourths (int x)
{
    return (int)((double)x * 0.75);
}
```

Comment: I get almost your points except how the enumeration table is drawn especially for the negative part. Could you explain that a bit more? I mean, how is the  negative sign bit making influences to the correction bias?

Comment: Or in other words, given the four left columns, how can I decide the right correction column? You first give the right column then get an expression using bit operations. So I'm not sure how it is calculated.

Comment: @lincr The corrections are determined by subtracting the value of the approximation `(x >> 1) + (x >> 2)` from the reference result, for representatives of each of eight remainder classes that need to be examined, e.g. use `x` in [`0x7FFFFFFC`, `0x80000003`]. The corrections are larger for negative `x` because *both* of the underestimation effects I listed occur in combination for negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to perform the problem.

Caveat: since this is integer math, there will be some lost precision

```
int threefourths(int x)
{
     long ret = x;

     // multiply by 3
     ret <<= 1;
     ret += x;

     // divide by 4
     ret >>= 2;
     return (int)ret;
}
```

Comment: It also readily overflows large `int` values (UB).  "the hard point is to truncate towards 0 and avoiding overflow."

Comment: @chux,  Your right, (my error) should have copied to a `long int` before maniuplating, so as to avoid any overflow of the variable,  I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Widening the integer math is a good idea - if possible, yet `long` (or even `intmax_t`) may not be wider than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached the problem assuming that it's not allowed to use multiplication, division and comparison operators and that right shifts are arithmetic shifts:

1. *Overflow*. To prevent the calculation from being overflowing we first perform the division by `4` and then multiply by `3`.
2. *Round toward 0*. The problem with rounding occurs when we divide the number by `4`. We need to perform right shift by `2` positions. For positives it rounds toward `0` out of the box, but for negatives it rounds away from `0`. To fix this we might bias our number a bit as described in the *Computer systems: A programmer's perspective* book:

> If `x` is negative then this expression `(x + (1 << k) - 1) >> k` performs division by `2^k` and rounds the result to `0`.

Having all of this in mind the code can be the following:

```c
int threefourths(int value)
{
    // size of int in bits - 1 (31 for most machines)
    int width = int_size_bits() - 1;

    int sign = (unsigned)value >> width;

    // perform the division by 4.
    // if value is positive, then sign is 0 and the expression is
    //      value >> 2
    // if value is negative, then sign is 1 and the expression is 
    //      value + (1 <<  2) - 1) >> 2
    int division = (value + (sign << 2) - sign) >> 2;

    // multiply by 3
    int mult = (division << 1) + division;

    return mult;
}
```